# Experimental values on scalar is now forbidden - perl

Tags: perl

Experimental values on scalar is now forbidden in old software:

```
$link = Winners::Links->new();
my @fields = $link->column_names;     
foreach my $field ( values @fields[0]) {
```

I tried to make :

```
 foreach my $field ( values {@fields[0]}) {

 foreach my $field ( values %{@fields[0]}) {

 foreach my $field ( values %@fields[0]) {
```

Non of them works. Any Idea how it should be done? Thx.

Here is more on @fields object definition:

```
[[
  'id',
  'entry',
  'selection',
  'status'
]]
```

Comment: You de-reference an array using the `$` sigil when you want a single value, not the `@` sigil. Try `foreach my $field ( values %{ $fields[0] } ) { ... }`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `@fields[0]` should probably be `$fields[0]` to get the first element of `@fields`.

Comment: This does not work - looks like `@fields[0]` is and multi array - as I am getting  `Not a HASH reference`

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `use Data::Dumper; print(Dumper(\@fields));`

Comment: Can you please show the *full* output of ikegami's command?

Comment: Is that really the full output? It doesn't start with `$VAR1 = [`?

Comment: yes, I had to take it via movable type backend, so '@fields[0]' as there is double array on this. so making it 'my @fl = $fields[0]' and then using it in 'foreach' - but still this does not work.

Comment: There's no hash there, so it doesn't make sense to use `values`. Also, what you've shown won't work even on old versions of perl: `perl -e'@fields = (['id', 'entry', 'selection', 'status']); values @fields[0]'` gives the error "Type of arg 1 to values must be hash (not array slice)" on 5.8.8. Can you please create a [mcve] that we can run on our own machines that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot newer perls can use values/keys/each on arrays.  values doens't make much sense, though

Comment: @ysth Wow, I did not realize that, thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This was added in Perl 5.14 but removed in 5.23:

> Experimental  `%s` on  scalar is  now forbidden  (F) An  experimental
>   feature  added in  Perl 5.14  allowed  each, keys,  push, pop,  shift,
>   splice, unshift, and values to be  called with a scalar argument. This
>   experiment  is  considered unsuccessful,  and  has  been removed.  The
>   postderef feature may meet your needs better.

So if you were  using it on a reference, dereference  it first. There is
some confusion arriving here though because of your original code:

```
foreach my $field ( values @fields[0]) {
```

Here `@fields[0]`  is actually a slice,  which is valid, and  works. But
with strict and warnings you would get something like:

```
Scalar value @fields[0] better written as $fields[0] at - line x.
```

In fact, if you're accessing an item (like a reference, probably in your
case) you should  be using `$fields[0]` instead. So  first correct that,
and then dereference to conform to the standard requirement for `values`
(being a list.  It accepted a scalar only as  an experimental feature in
the past).

```
foreach my $field ( values %{$fields[0]})
```

Answer (score 8):

You de-reference an array using the `$` sigil when you want a single value, not the `@` sigil.

Try using:

```
foreach my $field ( values %{ $fields[0] } ) {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested, but based on written definition of an AoA reference, I think:

```
foreach my $field ( @{ $fields[0] } ) {...}
```