# Directly access nested JSON data in perl?

Tags: arrays, json, perl, hash

I'm not familiar with hash/reference syntax with Perl and it makes my eyes hurt trying.
I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "Arg":"Custom_Light state alias protocol",
  "Results": [
  {
    "Name":"Custom_Light",
    "Internals": { },
    "Readings": {
      "protocol": { "Value":"V3", "Time":"2017-01-14 18:49:18" },
      "state": { "Value":"off", "Time":"2017-03-05 10:39:50" }
    },
    "Attributes": {      "alias": "Kitchen light" }
  }  ],
  "totalResultsReturned":1
}
```

How do I directly get the Reading > Protocol Value and Reading > state Value as well as the Attributes > Alias?

I am using the default `JSON` encoder/decoder and it works splendid. Using `Dumper($json)` I get all the JSON, but I have no clue how to directly access it without using foreach with all the arrays within arrays in this.

I have tried the following:

```
my $json = from_json( $readout, { utf8  => 1 } );
print "No. Entries:", scalar(keys($json)); #works, returns 3
my @results = %$json{Results};
Dumper(@results[1]); #I get the Results array
```

From here it already is ugly. What's that `%$` doing there? I thought I could do something like `print ${ $json->{'Results'}->[1] }{'Readings'};` but that leads me nowhere.

Give me wisdom. How do I access the Protocol value directly? How do I access the state value directly? And finally, how to get to the alias Attribute?

---

I don't know what I'm doing but I'm getting somewhere with `my $test = %{${%$json{Results}}[0]}{Name}; #I get "Custom_Light", nice`. Is this the way to go with a gazillion of weird `%` and `$` just randomly thrown in?

Comment: To get the `Value` field you could write: `$json->{Results}[0]{Readings}{state}{Value}`. And to get `alias` : `$json->{Results}[0]{Attributes}{alias}`

Comment: Yes! This looks pretty. Put it into an answer so I can give you some love.

Comment: *"What's that `%$` doing there?"* I was wondering that, but I thought you wrote it!

Comment: I did write it and it works. Found that `%$` after some sleuthing in forums on how to "dereference" (whatever that is, I know casting) hashtables in perl. Your solution looks **a lot better**

Comment: https://perlmonks.org?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), and [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), it will help  you understand how to access deeply nested structures in Perl.

> print "No. Entries:", scalar(keys($json)); #works, returns 3

Actually, this will no longer work. Using [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) on a scalar, was an experimental feature added in Perl 5.14 that allowed `each`, `keys`, `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `splice`, `unshift`, and `values` to be called with a scalar argument. This experiment was considered unsuccessful, and was removed in 5.23. See also [Experimental values on scalar is now forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41192532/2173773). So, you should dereference the hash reference `$json` before applying `keys`:

```
print "No. Entries:", scalar keys %$json;
```

As described in [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), `%$ref` dereferences the hash reference `$ref`. Next, lets look at this line:

> my @results = %$json{Results};

This actually first creates a new (anonymous) hash `( Result => $json->{Result} )` and then assigns this to `@results` making `@result = ( 'Result', $json->{Result} )`. So that is why you now can refer to `$json->{Result}[0]` as `$result[1]`.

But this is obscure coding, and probably not intended as well. So to return to your question, to get the `Value` field you could write:

```
my $value = $json->{Results}[0]{Readings}{state}{Value};
```

And to get the `alias` field:

```
my $alias = $json->{Results}[0]{Attributes}{alias};
```

Answer (score 5):

You want

```
$json->{Results}[0]{Readings}{protocol}{Value}
```

```
$json->{Results}[0]{Readings}{state}{Value}
```

```
$json->{Results}[0]{Attributes}{alias}
```

However, since the `Results` item is an array, you are likely to want to iterate over all of its elements, although in this case there is only one element

I find it useful to extract one level of reference at a time into temporary variables. It would look like this

```
my $results = $json->{Results};

for my $result ( @$results ) {

    my $readings   = $result->{Readings};
    my $attributes = $result->{Attributes};

    printf "Protocol: %s\n", $readings->{protocol}{Value};
    printf "State:    %s\n", $readings->{state}{Value};
    printf "Alias:    %s\n", $attributes->{alias};
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking about the results being an array!