# Retrieving hash-keys from map

Tags: regex, perl, hashmap

There is some string with words, separated by spaces. I need to gain an array of words with specific substring in every word, the words should be unique. It could be done e.g. such way:

```
%arr = map { $_ => 1 } grep /foo/, $str=~/\b(\w+)\b/g;
@arr = keys %arr;
```

But this is one-liner and to be concise I tried to do:

```
@arr = keys map { $_ => 1 } grep /foo/, $str=~/\b(\w+)\b/g;
```

However I got the error (in Perl 5.24.1):

> Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden

Unfortunately [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192532/experimental-values-on-scalar-is-now-forbidden-perl) and [2](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1214264) posts didn't help me to understand how it should be done properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to actually create a hash!

```
my @arr = keys %{ +{ map { $_ => 1 } grep /foo/, $str =~ /\b(\w+)\b/g } };
```

But there's a better way of getting rid of duplicates.

```
my %seen;
my @arr = grep !$seen{$_}++, grep /foo/, $str =~ /\b(\w+)\b/g;
```

or

```
sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }

my @arr = uniq grep /foo/, $str =~ /\b(\w+)\b/g;
```

or

```
use List::Util qw( uniq );

my @arr = uniq grep /foo/, $str =~ /\b(\w+)\b/g;
```

---

By the way,

```
grep /foo/, $str =~ /\b(\w+)\b/g
```

can be simplified to

```
$str =~ /\b\w*foo\w*+/g
```

Comment: I like the invocation `use List::Util 1.45 'uniq';` in examples as it results in a clearer error message if people blindly copy paste the code and don't have a new enough List::Util.

Comment: More specifically, the installer should have a dependency on List::Util version 1.45. There's no need to specify it against in the script or module.

Comment: It should, yes, but that's assuming the person who copy-pasted it has a dependency toolchain set up for their project, and I don't like to assume; plus it's easier to get people to use useful tools if they don't have to install things first (and if they're on Perl 5.26+, they don't, in this case).